# How to add padding-top to body in bootstrap3 with custom css file?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, customization

How to add padding-top to body in bootstrap3 with custom css file?
I know it can be done with  in html file, but I am trying to do it with custom css file, but it doesn't work.
Here is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Basic html site</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">  
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" >
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand-noPadding"><img src="images/logo50x149.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
         </nav>
         <!--etc -->
    </body>
</html>
```

and here custom.css:

```
 .navbar-brand-noPadding {
    padding: 0px 15px;
}

body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Comment: It should work. Try adding `!important`.

Comment: please create a jsFiddle file http://jsfiddle.net/, also include bootstrap.min.css so that we can understand the issue.

Comment: I think you want the padding for fixed navbar?! If yes, Try a new div after .navbar and add margin-top to it.

Comment: @GINCHER:!important didn't work.

Comment: @ColoO: Thanks. Removing semicolons after curly brackets did the job. I would never notice it. Now everything works fine.

Comment: If you've resolved the issue then post an answer or delete the question

Comment: no problem for that ;)